# Bring FrameLayout on top of every View

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I've got this layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/description_root_View"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/CardView_CornerRadius"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/CardView_elevation"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:background="@color/escription_background"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/SwipeView">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/View_margins">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/description_FrameLayout_profile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/description_FrameLayout_profile"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/description_FrameLayout_profile"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/description_ImageView_profile"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/description_ImageView_profile"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/description_ImageView_profile"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_photo"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

   <View
    android:id="@+id/View_layer_over"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/fragment_tutorial_layer_background"
    android:elevation="@dimen/adapter_versus_CardView_elevation"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

In the begining the View `View_layer_over` is a semi-transparent view that is on top of everything in my layout. When i press a button i wanna bring the `description_FrameLayout_profile` FrameLayout on top of the `View_layer_over` View. I have tried the `View.bringToFront()` method and `ViewCompat.setTranslationZ()`, after both of them i have called `Parent.invalidate()`, but none of them worked for me. I think it has something to do with the elevation attribute.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand exactly what you want, but what I'd do in this situation is have the ConstraintLayout be the parent/root view, which would contain your 'View_layer_over" view, and your CardView. If you set your constraints correctly, you'd get the behavior I think you want...

Comment: I already have a ConstraintLayout that is the root of all the elements above. The code i provided is just a snippet. What i actually want is the FrameLayout to be over the layer view when a button is pressed. Thanks for your answer